# Visual Studio Windows Forms Deleted records don't stay deleted

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, delete-row

I have a **Main** form with a *DataGridView* of a local table.  I have an **Inspections** form which has both *DataGridView* and *Detail* view of the same local table.  When I add a record on the **Inspections** form and go back to the **Main** form, it shows it added to that *DataGridView* as well.  But when I delete a record on the **Inspections** form, although it deletes it in both the *DataGridView* and *Details* view, when I go back to the **Main** form, the record has reappeared.  Then when I return to the **inspections** form, it has reappeared there as well.

It's not an issue of looking in the wrong place, I specifically loaded records in the BIN/DEBUG location table with different descriptions from the regular location so I could tell the difference.  The reappearing records are from the BIN/DEBUG location, which is where I deleted them from.

Comment: Please provide us with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not sure how much more of an example I can provide, I didn't code anything.  In creating the form, I just dragged the table from _Datasources_ onto the form, and the underlying code was automatically created, including a toolbar with **Add New**, **Delete** and **Save** buttons.  When I run the form and click the **Delete** button that was automatically created, the record disappears like it was deleted, but then when I go to a different form and come back, it's there again.  Do I need to add code to the auto-created **Delete** button?

Comment: Okay, figured part of it out.  If I click the **Delete** button, then the **Save** button, it stays deleted.  I guess I'll have to update Microsoft's automated code because (surprise) it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following code to the underlying Delete button:

```
    this.Validate();
    this.MyBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.MyDataSet);
```